# What is the filter size on the Canon PowerShot SX500 IS?

Tags: lens, canon, filters

What is the filter size of the lens on the PowerShot SX500 IS?

Comment: Related, if not *quite* a duplicate: [What is an appropriate set of filters for a Canon PowerShot SX30 IS?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/what-is-an-appropriate-set-of-filters-for-a-canon-powershot-sx30-is). In particular, see drewbenn's answer for a link to the adapter you'll need to mount any filters at all.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed. The Canon Powershot SX500 IS doesn't have filter threads.

However, this [adapter for 52mm filters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A9HJ50U) on Amazon has a few good reviews. Rather than using threads, it relies on friction fit to the concentric ridges inside the end of the lens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image below there doesn't seem to be any filter threads on the end of the lens barrel.

[image]