# What filter size for a Canon PowerShot SX430 IS?

Tags: lens, canon, filters

What size lens filter do I need for a Canon PowerShot SX430 IS? I have a 40.5mm UV filter, but it does not fit.

Comment: [You may want to consider not putting a UV filter on at all](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/what-effect-does-a-uv-filter-provide)

Answer (score 2):

The [PowerShot SX430 IS manual](https://www.camerauserguide.net/canon-powershot-sx430-is-camera-user-manual-instruction-manual-user-guide-pdf/29635) mentions neither filter thread size nor compatible filter adapters.

How certain are you that your camera has actual filter threads? Other Canon PowerShot SX# IS cameras do not have filter threads. Some have concentric rings to hold the lens cap in place. Some can use filters with a filter adapter.

If you are able to determine whether the lens cap is interchangeable between your camera and other PowerShot SX# IS models, the [FA-DC67A](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART117284) filter adapter *may* also fit your camera.

See also:

- [What is the filter size on the Canon PowerShot SX500 IS?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47711/75526)
- [Which is the correct filter size for Canon SX30 IS?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10664/75526)
- [What is an appropriate set of filters for a Canon PowerShot SX30 IS?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8234/75526)